# How to unescape JSON stringified textarea value?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a textarea html element and I want to save its value to a JSON file by stringifying it:

```js
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const rawText = document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
  const jsonText = JSON.stringify(rawText);
  console.log(jsonText);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button id="button">log json stringified</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running the snippet above, we can see two problems:

1. When the user types in a special character, `JSON.stringify()` automatically escapes it.
2. When the user enters a new line, `JSON.stringify()` adds a `\n` special character.

How to format the output such that it preserves any special characters that the user types and ignores new lines entered by the user?

For example when user types in:

```
one\ntwo\tthree\\nfour
five
```

I want to log:

```
"one\ntwo\tthree\\nfourfive"
```

Instead I am currently logging:

```
"one\\ntwo\\tthree\\\\nfour\nfive"
```

Comment: `one\ntwo\tthree\\nfourfive` is not valid `JSON`, so perhaps you should use a different format to store those values, something more appropriate.

Comment: @goto1 sorry I meant a string: "one\ntwo\tthree\\nfourfive"

Comment: That's still invalid `JSON`, if you just want to store some text then why not just store it in a text file.

Comment: @goto1 I am going to nest the string in some JSON object, this is just for demo purposes

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the new lines:

```
const rawText = document.querySelector("#textarea").value.replace(/\n/g, "");;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from Eugen Sunic's answer, the solution is:

```
const rawText = document.querySelector("#textarea").value.replace(/\n/g, "");
const jsonText = JSON.stringify(rawText).replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
```